# Python Selenium. Parallel if loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, loops, web-scraping

```
import csv
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from csv import reader
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


chrome_options = Options()
scroll = 5
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
header_added = False
header_added1 = False
url = "url"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
search_city = input("Enter the city :")
res_n = input("Enter the Restaurant's name :")
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="location"]').send_keys(search_city)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/span[2]').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/header/div/div/ul/li[5]/div/a/span[1]').click()
time.sleep(1)
search_res = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_2BJMh').send_keys(res_n.lower())
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('_2BJMh').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)

try:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3FR5S').click()
    time.sleep(5)
except:
    print("restaurant not open")
    driver.quit()

html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')



def get_items():
    global header_added
    global item_dvs
    cats = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('D_TFT')
    cats[1].click()
    time.sleep(3)
    item_dvs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_2wg_t')

    for div in item_dvs:
        name = div.find_element_by_class_name('styles_itemNameText__3bcKX')
        print(name.text)
        price = div.find_element_by_class_name('rupee')
        print(price.text)
        if div.find_elements_by_class_name('styles_itemDesc__MTsVd'):
            desc = div.find_element_by_class_name('styles_itemDesc__MTsVd').text
        else:
            desc = None
        if div.find_element_by_css_selector('div._1C1Fl._23qjy'):
            element = div.find_element_by_css_selector('div._1C1Fl._23qjy')
            print("found")
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
            add = div.find_element_by_css_selector('._1RPOp')
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", add)
            time.sleep(1)
            add_ons = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3UzO2').text
            print(add_ons)
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#modal-placeholder > div:nth-child(3) > div > div._1Kr-y._3EeZR > div > div._1EZLh > div > button').click()

        else:
            add_ons = None
        dict1 = {'Item Name': name.text, "Price": price.text, "Add Ons :": add_ons, "Description": desc}
        with open(f'{search_city}_{res_n}.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, dict1.keys())
            if not header_added:
                w.writeheader()
                header_added = True
            w.writerow(dict1)


get_items()
```

The `is_cust` loop keeps running over and over again opening the same element, while the rest of the code moves on to the next `divs`. What is wrong here?

Comment: I never use xPath, but they are bidirectional https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-are-the-differences-between-xpath-and-css-in-selenium-with-python... which might be in cause here. If you were using cssSelector, your ```div.find_element_by_css_selector``` would only retrieve the Childs of the parent div

Comment: Also your ```if/else``` statement is wrong. Your ```is_cust``` will either return an element or raise an exception. It can never be false

Comment: How so? and what is the solution?

Comment: You are using a parent element to find a nested element (div.find...), but xPath won't care much about it from what I read. I provided an answer, but without html code it is hard to give you an accurate explanation/solution. One thing a noticed is that you are mixing (driver and div) to search your elements. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xPath are [bidirectional](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-are-the-differences-between-xpath-and-css-in-selenium-with-python) and is probably the cause here.

Try this code using cssSelector:

```
for div in item_dvs:
    #Do Something

    try:   
        is_cust = div.find_element_by_css_selector('._1C1Fl._23qjy')
        print("found")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        continue

    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", is_cust)
    add = div.find_element_by_css_selector('._1RPOp')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", add)
    time.sleep(1)
    # Not sure why for this one you had driver instead of div. Suspect div should be 
    add_ons = div.find_element_by_class_name('_26cJ9').text
    div.find_element_by_css_selector('#modal-placeholder > div:nth-child(3) >   div > div._1Kr-y._3EeZR > div > div._1EZLh > div > button').click()
```

**UPDATE**
From your updated code, you are using lot of hardcoded sleep. I will suggest to use the `WebDriverWait` with `expected_conditions`.

More info here: [Wait from Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Imports needed:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Code to be added post driver creation:

wait_time = 5
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, wait_time)

Instead of using sleep like this:

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('_2BJMh').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
```

Use:

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, '_2BJMh'))).send_keys(res_n.lower())
```

Don't gather the element twice.. use `find_elements_by*` then validate the length:

```
descs = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'styles_itemDesc__MTsVd')))
if len(descs) > 0:
    desc = descs[0].text
else:
    desc = None
```

Comment: You see the `click`. It is a different window. That is why the `driver`. Also, I tried with the `css`. Same result. I will re run it just to make sure.

Comment: It worked !..Alas only for a few divs. Looks like you have your finger on the problem..Not sure why it isn't working for the rest...let me check.

Comment: Nice.. getting there! Can you provide more info when it does not work. If you open a new window/pop-up you might need to introduce ```WebDriverWait``` to allow the element to be loaded in the DOM

Comment: Are you able to share the html/site. And if so, provide how you retrieve ```item_dvs```

Comment: No, it's like you mentioned. When it doesn't find the element it doesn't go to else. Throws an error.

Comment: I need it in an `if` loop..because I am writing it in a dict. If the value of `addon` is None..I need to set it so..else the dict won't write.

Comment: Let me just add the link in the question and the entire code. Done adding. Sorry added an older code. Updated now.

Comment: Then get the list of elements. Also will suggest to use ```WebDriverWait``` and remove all hardcoded sleep. Just to confirm it is working just we skip the writing to a dict when the element is not there?

Comment: If we skip it..the dict will remain empty. There are any other elements without the customize options..I need those.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226493/discussion-between-nic-laforge-and-abhishek-rai).